# jq: error: Cannot index string with string

Tags: json, syntax, jq

I am trying to extract "ip_address" information from json, but after several failed attempts, I still cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Source file:

```
[
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "External gateway info": "{\"network_id\": \"68719cf1-xxxx\", \"enable_snat\": true, \"external_fixed_ips\": [{\"subnet_id\": \"b55dc621-xxxx\", \"ip_address\": \"10.10.10.11\"}]}",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "Tags": "",
    "Availability zones": "xxxx",
    "Project": "xxxx",
    "State": "UP",
    "Routes": "",
    "HA": true,
    "ID": "f9f7e5b1-xxxx"
  },
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "External gateway info": "{\"network_id\": \"68719cf1-xxxx\", \"enable_snat\": true, \"external_fixed_ips\": [{\"subnet_id\": \"b55dc621-xxxx\", \"ip_address\": \"10.10.10.12\"}]}",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "Tags": "",
    "Availability zones": "xxxx",
    "Project": "xxxx",
    "State": "UP",
    "Routes": "",
    "HA": true,
    "ID": "fbaa19aa-xxxx"
  },
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "External gateway info": "{\"network_id\": \"68719cf1-xxxx\", \"enable_snat\": true, \"external_fixed_ips\": [{\"subnet_id\": \"b55dc621-xxxx\", \"ip_address\": \"10.10.10.13\"}]}",
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "Tags": "",
    "Availability zones": "xxxx",
    "Project": "xxxx",
    "State": "UP",
    "Routes": "",
    "HA": true,
    "ID": "fe2abdd8-xxxx"
  },
  {
    "Status": "ACTIVE",
    "External gateway info": null,
    "Name": "xxxx",
    "Tags": "",
    "Availability zones": "xxxx",
    "Project": "xxxx",
    "State": "UP",
    "Routes": "",
    "HA": true,
    "ID": "ff29444d-xxxx"
  }
]
```

I have tried to use this command/syntax:

```
jq -r '.[]."External gateway info" | {external_fixed_ips} | .[].ip_address'
```

but getting the following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1934): Cannot index string with string "external_fixed_ips"
```

I was expecting to extract the "ip_address" from this json but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value under `."External gateway info"` is JSON encoded. Decode it using `fromjson`. Using the error suppression operator `?` in combination handles the cases where the key is missing.

```bash
jq -r '.[]."External gateway info" | fromjson? | .external_fixed_ips[].ip_address'
```

```
10.10.10.11
10.10.10.12
10.10.10.13
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! In the meantime I found another way to parse it, but your solution is more clean and correct.